# How to calculate the kurtosis of the sum of these ±1 random variables?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

There is an inverted triangle with n rows. The first line is $n$ independent random variables, each with a probability of $0.5$ taken as $1$ or $-1$. Starting from the second line, each random variable is the product of its upper left and upper right random variables. Record the sum of all random variables in this inverted triangle as $X$ and calculate the kurtosis of $X$.

My idea: It is easy to prove that $EX=0$ and the expectation of the product of any two random variables in this inverted triangle is also $0$, so its second-order central moment is easy to calculate. The difficulty lies in calculating the fourth order center moment. I found that the random variables in the second row are also independent of each other, so I guess we can use the recursive method to solve this problem. In the process of calculating $EX^4$, there are four types of products with non zero expectations, among which Type $4$ and Type $22$ are both easy to solve, but Type $1111$ is very complex. This prevents me from directly using recursive methods.

Comment: I didn't know triangles had rows.